# Check if two strings have two consecutive characters in common

Tags: ruby

I need to check if two strings have two consecutive characters in common.

I wrote this so far:

```
 def substring_test(str1, str2)
  return false if str1 == "" || str2 == ""
  str1.downcase.scan(/.{1,2}/).each do |pair|
     if str2.downcase.scan(/.{1,2}/).include? pair
       return true
     else 
       return false
     end
  end
end
```

But it doesn't work if I have: 
"Home" and "om" because it truncates the string every two characters. What condition could I add so it works in these cases ? I could add a condition truncating the string each two characters after the fist character but it feels like there could be an easier way?

Comment: `str.split('').each_cons(2).each` should be helpful in this case - Refer [`Enumerable#each_cons`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.3.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-each_cons)

Comment: Do you also consider a space a "character"?

Comment: @Drenmi I don't since str1 and str2 will only be one word strings

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could do something like

```
def substring_test(str1, str2)
    str1.each_char.each_cons(2).any? { |pair| str2.include? (pair.join) }
end
```

Using the `any?` method will exit the loop as soon as it finds its first match.

Comment: `any?` exits too and returns a boolean.

Comment: One potential disadvantage is that `str1.include?` is executed for each pair. If a matching pair is normally found early on, that may not be an issue, but if not, you may want to first create a set: `require 'set'; pairs = str2.each_char.each_cons(2).to_set`, then `pairs.include?(pair)`, which would be fast.

Answer (score 4):

Here is my variant:

```
def split_by_2_chars(string)
  (0..string.size - 2).map { |i| string[i..i + 1].downcase }
end

def substring_test(s1, s2)
  (split_by_2_chars(s1) & split_by_2_chars(s2)).any?
end

puts substring_test("Home", "om")   #=> true
puts substring_test("Abcd", "defg") #=> false
```

Comment: Set intersection is what I would have used as well, but what's wrong with `each_cons`?

Comment: @JörgWMittag yeah, `each_cons` is probably an easier way, but it's already noticed in other answers.

Comment: this is cleaner much.

Comment: Array intersection does have the disadvantage that all the adjacent pairs of each string are first generated, even though the OP only wants to know if there is at least one match. If, for example, both strings began with `"ab"`, @Martin's approach would be much faster.

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do this.  Use of `Enumerable#any?` helps us to keep the number of loop iterations to minimum as it will exit as soon as match is found.

```
s1 = "Home"
s2 = "Rome"

s1.downcase.split('').each_cons(2).any? do |c1|
    s2.downcase.split('').each_cons(2).any?{|c2| c2 == c1}
end
#=> true
```